# WMI query to get VisualSVN Server User Access Rights in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, visual-c++-6, visualsvn-server, wmi-query

How to get VisualSVN Server User Access Rights by using WMI Query in VC++.

I am writing a vc++ application to get & set User Access Rights of VisualSVN Server by using WMI query.

we able to get the Associatedobject and getting repository name and paths by using

```
 VARIANT vtProp;
 hres = pclsObj->Get(L"AssociatedObject", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
 wcout <<L"Values : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
```

But not getting the Permission object values, The permission contains the collection object.

```
 hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Permissions", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);  
 SAFEARRAY *pSafeArray = vtProp.parray; 
 LONG uBound = -1, lBound = 0;
 SafeArrayGetUBound(pSafeArray,1,&uBound);
 SafeArrayGetLBound(pSafeArray,1,&lBound);
 int nCount = uBound - lBound + 1;
 for(int i = 0; i<nCount; ++i)
 {
     wcout << ((BSTR*)(pSafeArray->pvData))[i] << endl;
 }
```

But not getting the object values. How to get the Unknown object values from the SafeArray.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Starting with VisualSVN Server 3.4, the server comes with a number PowerShell cmdlets developed for such tasks. For example, to get all access rules for all users and repositories run the PowerShell cmdlet [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule).

For information on other VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets and usage examples, read the article [*KB88: VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference*](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).