# How to get and process object from SafeArray vc++

Tags: visual-c++-6, visualsvn

I have used the variant datatype to get the list of VisualSVN_PermissionEnrty objects from WMI query and stored it into the safearray.

Now the safearray contains the list of VisualSVN_PermissionEnrty object. how can i read the values from the safearray objects.

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WMI query to get VisualSVN Server User Access Rights in vc++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109662/wmi-query-to-get-visualsvn-server-user-access-rights-in-vc)